# Run Macro from Desktop Shortcut

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript, macros

I wrote a macro that does some calculations based on a particular type of excel sheet.  Im trying to distribute this to my coworkers but the addition of a macro to a workbook and then running the macro is something foreign to them.  I'd like to have a "shortcut" or some VBS program to open a specific workbook (specified by the user), run the macro, and display the results.

Your help is appreciated!

--Edit--
I wrote a macro in VBA.  I exported the file to my desktop.  Its simply called "Macro1".  We have a standard form of excel sheet our company uses.  Its literally the same sheet with different numbers.  The macro I designed works on these kinds of sheets and does calculations.  My coworkers aren't good with macros, so I want some sort of "code" that will prompt one of my coworkers for an excel file, then execute the macro on the file.  Hopefully this clarifies any questions.

Comment: @JohnColeman  I have spent a large portion of my time trying to find an answer for this and it isn't out there.

Comment: The truth is out there! :-) I have the exact same requirement except it's CSV files. My add-in code detects if I open a csv file it checks if the file has the correct content and then asks if I want to do the add-in calculations. And the self install and auto update over internet for my users :-)

Comment: just tell me if you need help implementing the code with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make it a excel add-in.

Then in the add-in make it run on workbook open with `Sub App_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)` in thisworkbook.

In the macro you can then have it only activate on certain workbook name or workbook type by:

```
If range("A1").value = "something" ' something that makes the workbook type special.
' Maybe you need B1 value and so on too.
```

Do you need a way to self-install the add in just let me know and I have a code for that too.

Self install:

```
' if add-in is not installed and the workbook is a add-in (workbookcount =0)
' Also take note that this code will only run if the add-in is not installed
If Dir(Application.UserLibraryPath & "YourWorkbookName.xlam") = "" And Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
     'optional ask user if he wants to install or not. Code not included.

     ' copy file from current position to add-ins folder.
     Result = apiCopyFile(ThisWorkbook.FullName, Application.UserLibraryPath & "YourWorkbookName.xlam", False)
     ' activate the add-in
     AddIns("YourAdd-inName").Installed = True

     msgbox("add-in installed")

     ' Close Excel since add-ins does not work without restart of Excel
     On Error Resume Next
     Application.Interactive = False
     AppActivate "Microsoft Excel"
     Application.Quit
     Exit Sub 
End If
```

Note that the file **must** be saved as a add-in. (xlam) this means there is no sheets, the workbook is VBA code only.
Normally, that does not mean the code needs to be written in a special way.
Usually Range("XX").value works, but some commands may need to point towards the correct workbook. (you have two workbooks open with add-ins, the add-in with the code and the workbook with the sheets and numbers)

Hope this helps

Comment: If you could, yes I do need a self-install for add-in.